# MWWA Airflow web login token usage

Tags: airflow, token, mwaa

I have setup a MWAA Airflow v2.7.2 in PRIVATE access mode and works ok. I am able to hit endpoints from my local terminal using cli token.

Per the AWS documentation I can also create on my local terminal a web login token. Their example produces a URL which contains the token. If i copy/paste it to my browser, the Airflow UI opens. However the documentation states the following:

```
You can use the commands on this page to generate a web login token, and then make Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow API calls directly in your command shell. For example, you can get a token, then deploy DAGs programmatically using Amazon MWAA APIs.
```

I cannot find anywhere an example of how to use the web token to hit the API. Sorry for my basic question, but I don't understand what I can do with this web login token and more importantly how to do it.

Any explanations would be appreciated.

I was expecting that by creating the web login token, I would be able to hit the Airflow API, which is what the AWS documentation states, but I just don't know how.